# Google Could storage ETIMEDOUT connection issue

Tags: sockets, websocket, google-cloud-storage

We are using @google-cloud/storage package on a node server and we are seeing intermittent connection issues when opening a socket to google-cloud storage. It looks like the issue is connecting with the auth but Im trying to figure out why something like this would happen? Any help would be greatly appreciated and please let me know if there is any more information that would help in understanding the problem so that if others are facing the same issue it can help them as well.

```
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718075+00:00 app[web.1]: { Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.7.170:443
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718076+00:00 app[web.1]: at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718078+00:00 app[web.1]: at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718080+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1099:14)
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718082+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718083+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718084+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718084+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '172.217.7.170',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718086+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 443,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718087+00:00 app[web.1]: config:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718088+00:00 app[web.1]: { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718089+00:00 app[web.1]: transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718091+00:00 app[web.1]: transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718091+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718092+00:00 app[web.1]: xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718093+00:00 app[web.1]: xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718095+00:00 app[web.1]: validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718094+00:00 app[web.1]: maxContentLength: -1,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718096+00:00 app[web.1]: headers:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718097+00:00 app[web.1]: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718098+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718099+00:00 app[web.1]: 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.18.0',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718100+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Length': 827 },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718101+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'post',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718102+00:00 app[web.1]: url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718104+00:00 app[web.1]: data: '...'},
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718105+00:00 app[web.1]: request:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718106+00:00 app[web.1]: Writable {
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718107+00:00 app[web.1]: _writableState:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718108+00:00 app[web.1]: WritableState {
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718109+00:00 app[web.1]: objectMode: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718110+00:00 app[web.1]: highWaterMark: 16384,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718111+00:00 app[web.1]: needDrain: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718111+00:00 app[web.1]: ending: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718112+00:00 app[web.1]: ended: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718113+00:00 app[web.1]: finished: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718114+00:00 app[web.1]: decodeStrings: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718115+00:00 app[web.1]: defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718116+00:00 app[web.1]: length: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718117+00:00 app[web.1]: writing: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718118+00:00 app[web.1]: sync: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718118+00:00 app[web.1]: corked: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718119+00:00 app[web.1]: bufferProcessing: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718120+00:00 app[web.1]: onwrite: [Function],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718121+00:00 app[web.1]: writecb: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718122+00:00 app[web.1]: writelen: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718123+00:00 app[web.1]: bufferedRequest: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718124+00:00 app[web.1]: lastBufferedRequest: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718125+00:00 app[web.1]: pendingcb: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718126+00:00 app[web.1]: prefinished: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718127+00:00 app[web.1]: errorEmitted: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718128+00:00 app[web.1]: bufferedRequestCount: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718129+00:00 app[web.1]: corkedRequestsFree: [Object] },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718130+00:00 app[web.1]: writable: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718131+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718132+00:00 app[web.1]: _events:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718133+00:00 app[web.1]: { response: [Function: handleResponse],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718134+00:00 app[web.1]: error: [Function: handleRequestError] },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718135+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 2,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718136+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718137+00:00 app[web.1]: _options:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718137+00:00 app[web.1]: { protocol: 'https:',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718138+00:00 app[web.1]: maxRedirects: 21,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718139+00:00 app[web.1]: maxBodyLength: 10485760,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718140+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/oauth2/v4/token',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718141+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'post',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718142+00:00 app[web.1]: headers: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718143+00:00 app[web.1]: agent: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718144+00:00 app[web.1]: auth: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718145+00:00 app[web.1]: hostname: 'www.googleapis.com',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718145+00:00 app[web.1]: port: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718146+00:00 app[web.1]: nativeProtocols: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718147+00:00 app[web.1]: pathname: '/oauth2/v4/token' },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718148+00:00 app[web.1]: _redirectCount: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718149+00:00 app[web.1]: _redirects: [],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718150+00:00 app[web.1]: _requestBodyLength: 827,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718150+00:00 app[web.1]: _requestBodyBuffers: [ [Object] ],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718151+00:00 app[web.1]: _onNativeResponse: [Function],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718152+00:00 app[web.1]: _currentRequest:
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718153+00:00 app[web.1]: ClientRequest {
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718154+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718155+00:00 app[web.1]: _events: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718156+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 6,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718156+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718157+00:00 app[web.1]: output: [],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718158+00:00 app[web.1]: outputEncodings: [],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718159+00:00 app[web.1]: outputCallbacks: [],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718160+00:00 app[web.1]: outputSize: 0,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718161+00:00 app[web.1]: writable: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718162+00:00 app[web.1]: _last: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718163+00:00 app[web.1]: upgrading: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718164+00:00 app[web.1]: chunkedEncoding: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718165+00:00 app[web.1]: shouldKeepAlive: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718166+00:00 app[web.1]: useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718167+00:00 app[web.1]: sendDate: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718168+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedHeader: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718169+00:00 app[web.1]: _contentLength: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718170+00:00 app[web.1]: _hasBody: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718171+00:00 app[web.1]: _trailer: '',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718171+00:00 app[web.1]: finished: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718172+00:00 app[web.1]: _headerSent: true,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718173+00:00 app[web.1]: socket: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718174+00:00 app[web.1]: connection: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718180+00:00 app[web.1]: _header: 'POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.18.0\r\nContent-Length: 827\r\nHost: www.googleapis.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718182+00:00 app[web.1]: _headerNames: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718181+00:00 app[web.1]: _headers: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718183+00:00 app[web.1]: _onPendingData: null,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718184+00:00 app[web.1]: agent: [Object],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718185+00:00 app[web.1]: socketPath: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718186+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: undefined,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718186+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'POST',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718187+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/oauth2/v4/token',
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718188+00:00 app[web.1]: _ended: false,
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718189+00:00 app[web.1]: _redirectable: [Circular],
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718190+00:00 app[web.1]: parser: null },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718191+00:00 app[web.1]: _currentUrl: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token' },
2018-08-04T17:07:56.718192+00:00 app[web.1]: response: undefined }
```

More context:

```
node 6.11 
deployed on heroku
```

the code that is creating the socket:

```
export function createGCSBucketClient(options = defaultGCSOptions) {
  const { projectId, keyFilename, bucketName } = options;
  const gcs = require('@google-cloud/storage')({ // eslint-disable-line global-require
    projectId,
    keyFilename,
  });
  return gcs.bucket(bucketName);
}
```

This function is then being used in multiple places throughout our code.

Comment: Getting the snippet of code doing the actual call would surely help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I added some more context including the code snippet making the call.

Comment: Looking at the failed URL, `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token`, it looks like the error is in the auth flow done by the library. Are you calling `createGCSBucketClient()` concurrently very often? If so, it might be worth trying to reuse the generated clients, so the auth flow is not executed every time.

Comment: we are getting the exact same error- request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 172.217.15.106:443. Were you ever able to figure out the root cause and fix this issue. @Alex